# Create Single Event ICS file with Expression Engine

Tags: php, expressionengine, icalendar

I'm trying to create an ICAL file based on a single entry inside an Expression Engine channel but my methods of accomplishing this are failing. I've tried the following:

1. Passing the entry ID into a new template (which creates the file) but using the `$_GET` function seems to be frowned upon in EE
2. Creating a session variable with the entry ID but there seems to be no way of adding this variable to the {exp} query:

   `{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" entry_id="MY_PHP_VARIABLE" limit="1" show_future_entries="yes"}`

I haven't tried just making a flat file each time the single entry page is accessed with `fwrite()` and linking directly to it, but that seems like a costly move.

Is there a way with PHP to make the file when I click a button? Maybe firing off a function written in the page so I don't need to pass or detect the `entry_id`?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before with a regular template with PHP enabled on output.

So your iCal link would be `/events/ical/{entry_id}`, and your `events.group/ical.html` template would look something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" sort="asc" show_future_entries="yes" limit="1" require_entry="yes" disable="member_data|categories|pagination"}
<?php
header('Content-type: text/calendar');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="event-{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}.ics"');
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:MY GREAT EVENTS
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY;CHARSET={charset}:{summary}
DESCRIPTION;CHARSET={charset}:{description}
LOCATION;CHARSET={charset}:{venue}, {address}
UID:{entry_date format="%Y%m%d"}-{entry_id}@mydomain.com
URL:{permalink="events/detail"}
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:{entry_date format="%Y%m%d"}
DTSTAMP:{entry_date format="%Y%m%d"}T000000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The details may vary of course, depending on whether you're using the time portion of your date fields, or a dedicated time field, etc, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this, but I needed the exact same thing and wrote a plugin to handle it.

https://github.com/expressodev/easy_icalendar

Basically, the usage just revolves around a standard channel entries tag, so looks something like this

```
{exp:easy_ical:calendar timezone="Pacific/Auckland" name="My Easy Event Calendar"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="events" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes" limit="20"}
        {exp:easy_ical:event uid="{entry_id}" start_time="{entry_date}" end_time="{expiration_date}" location="{event_location}" summary="{title}"}
            {event_description}
        {/exp:easy_ical:event}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:easy_ical:calendar}
```

You can use it to show a single entry when you click a button. Just make a new template called `/events/ical` or something, and reference it using the url `/events/ical/url-title` (or entry_id).

Then in your channel entries loop, use the standard

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" url_title="{segment_3}"}
```

Easy iCal will spit out a valid, downloadable ics file. If you want the link to have an *.ics extension (some readers are fussy), put the entry_id in segment 3, and the file name in segment 4:

```
<a href="/events/ical/{entry_id}/{url_title}.ics">
```

Then just use the entry_id in your ical template, and ignore segment 4